# Python LDAP MaxPageSize 1000

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap

Всем привет, есть скрипт python, через него я получаю инфу из Active Directory по LDAP, но есть единственный нюанс, в AD есть параметр MaxPageSize, он равен 1000. Соответственно, я получаю только 1000 объектов через скрипт, но я слышал, что можно получать инфу постранично. Собственно вопрос - как это реализовать?

```
import ldap
import csv

try:
    lconn = ldap.initialize('ldap://IP-AD-DC:389')
    lconn.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
    lconn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    lconn.simple_bind_s('user', 'password')
except ldap.SERVER_DOWN:
    print("Error connection to AD")

base = "DC=domain,DC=com"
scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(telephoneNumber=*))"
attrs = ['telephoneNumber','sAMAccountName']
result_set = []

ldap_result_id = lconn.search_ext(base, scope, filter, attrs)

try:
  while 1:
    result_type, result_data = lconn.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
    if (result_data == []):
      break
    else:
      if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
        result_set.append(result_data)
      with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(result_set)

except ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED:
    print()
```

Заранее спасибо!

PS: знаю, что можно повысить MaxPageSize, но это не наш метод)

Comment: А покажите пример скрипта (добавив в вопрос, кнопка `править`), чтобы было от чего отталкиваться :)

Comment: в ответе от AD имеется упоминание о странице? если да, подставляйте при следующем запросе